# 1991 Celica unable to start lately

Tags: toyota, starting, troubleshooting, fuel-injection, celica

I had some previous trouble with this car, I replaced the fuel pump and alternator as both were no longer operational. Now I am having a bad no start situation (this was also present in the last few days before removing the alternator) where it either cranks indefinitely or makes a half-attempt at starting but stalls soon after this - at most it lasted was 5 seconds with a very rough idle.

I'm wondering what it could be, I was suspicious of the fuel supply as it seemed like a lack of fuel but I cracked open a bolt on the fuel line which proceeded to spray out petrol. Granted this bolt is not at the fuel rail, but very close, so I'm still not convinced that fuel isn't the issue.

I have attempted to check for any vacuum leaks and cannot see any obvious damage to any of the lines, but I would've assumed it would need to be a bad leak to cause the issue I'm having?

And finally for spark, I checked all the spark plugs which were in surprisingly good condition bar one that was a bit oily by the looks of things, I had spark at all 4 plugs so I don't think that is the issue. I took a look at the distro cap and I definitely need a new rotor and cap once I have this issue sorted!

My guess is that there is not enough fuel being injected to start up fully / stay running. The only time I can get it to half-start is if it is left sit still for a few hours. If I try straight after this attempt all it does is crank - maybe the first attempt uses any residual fuel that is there??
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

So - Easy Start didn't make a difference, but the injectors are very awkwardly hidden below the manifold so I couldn't check the fuel supply to the rail.

I left it idle for a week (with the battery diconnected) and out of pure chance tried to start it 5 or 6 times today, each time it was getting a bit further to starting. Eventually it kicked into life and running smoothly, absolutely no idea what the problem was ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Advice for others: don't give up!

Answer (score 0):

Spray easy start in and see i/f this keps the car running-this will tell you if the ignition is ok, and therefore, its a fuel problem.  Fuel pressure needs to be exacting so i would get a pressure tester on the rail.  I take it the fuel is fresh and not old?

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that I tried Easy Start and this didn't help the situation, we still had a no start issue. There was little to no old fuel left in the tank a few weeks ago so it's fresh fuel in the system.

Before we replaced the fuel pump we were able to start it with Easy Start intermittently when testing then, but it was starting fine for a few weeks with the new pump until recently.

Comment: If its not starting with easy start, i would suggest no spark? Is there an immobiliser which would cut spark and fuel delivery?

Comment: The OP already stated there is spark at the spark plugs, though doesn't say how this was tested.

Comment: I don't think there is an immobiliser, but I will double check! Also for checking the spark plugs I removed each one and grounded them to the frame, probably not ideal testing. The contacts in the distributor cap and on the rotor are quite corroded but I wouldn't expect all 4 to fail at once in it's current state.